# Bech32 Multisig error: Witness requires empty scriptSig (code 64)

Tags: bitcoin-core, address, script, spending

I've been able to do multisig between two addresses from electrum and one from bitcoind.

```
[root@test bin]# bitcoin-cli -testnet getnewaddress
n3JewuY82cprdRvxHdRNG8C3iTkJBKeLbz

[root@test bin]# bitcoin-cli -testnet getaddressinfo n3JewuY82cprdRvxHdRNG8C3iTkJBKeLbz
{
  "address": "n3JewuY82cprdRvxHdRNG8C3iTkJBKeLbz",
  "scriptPubKey": "76a914eeff4b7b1c133c7f72c1b28c4d3c45fdf377c38788ac",
  "ismine": true,
  "solvable": true,
  "desc": "pkh([55e0eacd/0'/0'/23']0361ac153cfc0c5cefb74fa904ca83105ccdcbaa3c1ebb8266a03212619ae1006a)#egqffv76",
  "iswatchonly": false,
  "isscript": false,
  "iswitness": false,
  "pubkey": "0361ac153cfc0c5cefb74fa904ca83105ccdcbaa3c1ebb8266a03212619ae1006a",
  "iscompressed": true,
  "label": "",
  "ischange": false,
  "timestamp": 1576329907,
  "hdkeypath": "m/0'/0'/23'",
  "hdseedid": "763fc03352a1f347f5b5f1c57bf8e1bd1f1043ed",
  "hdmasterfingerprint": "55e0eacd",
  "labels": [
    {
      "name": "",
      "purpose": "receive"
    }
  ]
}

[root@test bin]# bitcoin-cli -testnet dumpprivkey n3JewuY82cprdRvxHdRNG8C3iTkJBKeLbz
cVvXTPL6ozGX9ckrNQ7gEudkPnEb6sPdtKPFEsLaQG38JdX1TXqn
```

I've created an address like this.

```
Wallet 1 (Electrum)

addr: tb1qp23cmwgn8qnv8cg5h595ne7nuvlvjhpxssee4d

pubkey: 02b1c24ff14bc3e9cab5ff65eda5365fc215449b8fbacb7615a6c8fe0c64ea2bba

privkey: cUY49HJ18YJXoBnbnbRwRFZN6ab89BtPinogSNeqqF6XdyU3R4xp

Wallet 2 (Electrum)

addr: tb1qvrtgw5pe3h97mk3kshqmkw7aff4qu6ftyy9v3a

pubkey: 039e28363fe72c1d84b04a15e491f3e85ee853be9f6e65257c373cb464c294900c

privkey: cNP1KSiJ2MZ8JfdjdyHjPHBJpnBeKLhF2xXTdbsD8CyV72GxiTeJ

Wallet 3 (bitcoind)

addr: n3JewuY82cprdRvxHdRNG8C3iTkJBKeLbz

pubkey: 0361ac153cfc0c5cefb74fa904ca83105ccdcbaa3c1ebb8266a03212619ae1006a

privkey: cVvXTPL6ozGX9ckrNQ7gEudkPnEb6sPdtKPFEsLaQG38JdX1TXqn
```

Here are the infos of those wallets.

```
[root@test bin]# bitcoin-cli -testnet createmultisig 2 '["02b1c24ff14bc3e9cab5ff65eda5365fc215449b8fbacb7615a6c8fe0c64ea2bba", "039e28363fe72c1d84b04a15e491f3e85ee853be9f6e65257c373cb464c294900c", "0361ac153cfc0c5cefb74fa904ca83105ccdcbaa3c1ebb8266a03212619ae1006a"]'
{
  "address": "2Mw3vye5PHPyjZJiLhNt2g7bBpv6MukAsqS",
  "redeemScript": "522102b1c24ff14bc3e9cab5ff65eda5365fc215449b8fbacb7615a6c8fe0c64ea2bba21039e28363fe72c1d84b04a15e491f3e85ee853be9f6e65257c373cb464c294900c210361ac153cfc0c5cefb74fa904ca83105ccdcbaa3c1ebb8266a03212619ae1006a53ae"
}
```

And created a *legacy* multisig address. After funding the multisig address, I created a spend transaction.

```
[root@test bin]# bitcoin-cli -testnet listunspent 0 9999 '["2Mw3vye5PHPyjZJiLhNt2g7bBpv6MukAsqS"]'
[
  {
    "txid": "c02b2342d8894092a2d89d45ebb140b3ec1c667b9167ee91e07efb67272f6c62",
    "vout": 0,
    "address": "2Mw3vye5PHPyjZJiLhNt2g7bBpv6MukAsqS",
    "label": "",
    "scriptPubKey": "a91429bdba3711f894e5876e4fe812be9adb25188e1c87",
    "amount": 0.00004000,
    "confirmations": 0,
    "spendable": false,
    "solvable": false,
    "safe": false
  }
]

[root@test bin]# bitcoin-cli -testnet createrawtransaction '[{"txid":"c02b2342d8894092a2d89d45ebb140b3ec1c667b9167ee91e07efb67272f6c62","vout":0,"scriptPubKey":"a91429bdba3711f894e5876e4fe812be9adb25188e1c87","redeemScript":"522102b1c24ff14bc3e9cab5ff65eda5365fc215449b8fbacb7615a6c8fe0c64ea2bba21039e28363fe72c1d84b04a15e491f3e85ee853be9f6e65257c373cb464c294900c210361ac153cfc0c5cefb74fa904ca83105ccdcbaa3c1ebb8266a03212619ae1006a53ae"}]' '{"tb1qnkvqy9p399dcjuqtmw8d6c49u53nf66g5z238w":0.000036}'
0200000001626c2f2767fb7ee091ee67917b661cecb340b1eb459dd8a2924089d842232bc00000000000ffffffff01100e0000000000001600149d98021431295b89700bdb8edd62a5e52334eb4800000000

[root@test bin]# bitcoin-cli -testnet signrawtransactionwithkey 0200000001626c2f2767fb7ee091ee67917b661cecb340b1eb459dd8a2924089d842232bc00000000000ffffffff01100e0000000000001600149d98021431295b89700bdb8edd62a5e52334eb4800000000 '["cVvXTPL6ozGX9ckrNQ7gEudkPnEb6sPdtKPFEsLaQG38JdX1TXqn"]' '[{"txid":"c02b2342d8894092a2d89d45ebb140b3ec1c667b9167ee91e07efb67272f6c62","vout":0,"scriptPubKey":"a91429bdba3711f894e5876e4fe812be9adb25188e1c87","redeemScript":"522102b1c24ff14bc3e9cab5ff65eda5365fc215449b8fbacb7615a6c8fe0c64ea2bba21039e28363fe72c1d84b04a15e491f3e85ee853be9f6e65257c373cb464c294900c210361ac153cfc0c5cefb74fa904ca83105ccdcbaa3c1ebb8266a03212619ae1006a53ae"}]'
{
  "hex": "0200000001626c2f2767fb7ee091ee67917b661cecb340b1eb459dd8a2924089d842232bc000000000b500473044022066c276bfe5fe2fe420119d780c6c1ee971ed7dce34c3a938d965464ab164098e02205dfaf4e6a6eab939ccc0f2efbd7a347ab02abb734e33684b925c873f521d496601004c69522102b1c24ff14bc3e9cab5ff65eda5365fc215449b8fbacb7615a6c8fe0c64ea2bba21039e28363fe72c1d84b04a15e491f3e85ee853be9f6e65257c373cb464c294900c210361ac153cfc0c5cefb74fa904ca83105ccdcbaa3c1ebb8266a03212619ae1006a53aeffffffff01100e0000000000001600149d98021431295b89700bdb8edd62a5e52334eb4800000000",
  "complete": false,
  "errors": [
    {
      "txid": "c02b2342d8894092a2d89d45ebb140b3ec1c667b9167ee91e07efb67272f6c62",
      "vout": 0,
      "witness": [
      ],
      "scriptSig": "00473044022066c276bfe5fe2fe420119d780c6c1ee971ed7dce34c3a938d965464ab164098e02205dfaf4e6a6eab939ccc0f2efbd7a347ab02abb734e33684b925c873f521d496601004c69522102b1c24ff14bc3e9cab5ff65eda5365fc215449b8fbacb7615a6c8fe0c64ea2bba21039e28363fe72c1d84b04a15e491f3e85ee853be9f6e65257c373cb464c294900c210361ac153cfc0c5cefb74fa904ca83105ccdcbaa3c1ebb8266a03212619ae1006a53ae",
      "sequence": 4294967295,
      "error": "CHECK(MULTI)SIG failing with non-zero signature (possibly need more signatures)"
    }
  ]
}
```

After signing the transaction with another wallet, I was able to broadcast the transaction with no hassle. Here's the result.

https://blockstream.info/testnet/tx/3420c45740088a85b2ae2ec439e1bafe3485358eb6f97cb73730b21ae69eac2b

---

So, with this method, I tried again but this time with **bech32** address to save fee.

```
[root@test bin]# bitcoin-cli -testnet getnewaddress '' bech32
tb1qantln64pdda5qwngxdqrq8dcghhu6w9r7ple9j

[root@test bin]# bitcoin-cli -testnet getaddressinfo tb1qantln64pdda5qwngxdqrq8dcghhu6w9r7ple9j
{
  "address": "tb1qantln64pdda5qwngxdqrq8dcghhu6w9r7ple9j",
  "scriptPubKey": "0014ecd7f9eaa16b7b403a683340301db845efcd38a3",
  "ismine": true,
  "solvable": true,
  "desc": "wpkh([55e0eacd/0'/0'/25']024cf34774923ce01a24faa65508d7b09f29aa50a64e11f204c8f3b2ad7a307ffd)#mjfxaggy",
  "iswatchonly": false,
  "isscript": false,
  "iswitness": true,
  "witness_version": 0,
  "witness_program": "ecd7f9eaa16b7b403a683340301db845efcd38a3",
  "pubkey": "024cf34774923ce01a24faa65508d7b09f29aa50a64e11f204c8f3b2ad7a307ffd",
  "label": "",
  "ischange": false,
  "timestamp": 1576329907,
  "hdkeypath": "m/0'/0'/25'",
  "hdseedid": "763fc03352a1f347f5b5f1c57bf8e1bd1f1043ed",
  "hdmasterfingerprint": "55e0eacd",
  "labels": [
    {
      "name": "",
      "purpose": "receive"
    }
  ]
}

[root@test bin]# bitcoin-cli -testnet dumpprivkey tb1qantln64pdda5qwngxdqrq8dcghhu6w9r7ple9j
cVoNiYk51W5E6xos2sMvP7XsR8QhDsw8JR6dof9cHw7S1UsechZd
```

```
Wallet 1 (Electrum)

addr: tb1qp23cmwgn8qnv8cg5h595ne7nuvlvjhpxssee4d

pubkey: 02b1c24ff14bc3e9cab5ff65eda5365fc215449b8fbacb7615a6c8fe0c64ea2bba

privkey: cUY49HJ18YJXoBnbnbRwRFZN6ab89BtPinogSNeqqF6XdyU3R4xp

Wallet 2 (Electrum)

addr: tb1qvrtgw5pe3h97mk3kshqmkw7aff4qu6ftyy9v3a

pubkey: 039e28363fe72c1d84b04a15e491f3e85ee853be9f6e65257c373cb464c294900c

privkey: cNP1KSiJ2MZ8JfdjdyHjPHBJpnBeKLhF2xXTdbsD8CyV72GxiTeJ

Wallet 3 (bitcoind)

addr: tb1qantln64pdda5qwngxdqrq8dcghhu6w9r7ple9j

pubkey: 024cf34774923ce01a24faa65508d7b09f29aa50a64e11f204c8f3b2ad7a307ffd

privkey: cVoNiYk51W5E6xos2sMvP7XsR8QhDsw8JR6dof9cHw7S1UsechZd
```

I created a *bech32* multisig address.

```
[root@test bin]# bitcoin-cli -testnet createmultisig 2 '["02b1c24ff14bc3e9cab5ff65eda5365fc215449b8fbacb7615a6c8fe0c64ea2bba", "039e28363fe72c1d84b04a15e491f3e85ee853be9f6e65257c373cb464c294900c", "024cf34774923ce01a24faa65508d7b09f29aa50a64e11f204c8f3b2ad7a307ffd"]' bech32
{
  "address": "tb1qxs6nsj4guvuxftz6pf8gydg6ga4d8flw342y2603vn52vyjm0u3qgxchhk",
  "redeemScript": "522102b1c24ff14bc3e9cab5ff65eda5365fc215449b8fbacb7615a6c8fe0c64ea2bba21039e28363fe72c1d84b04a15e491f3e85ee853be9f6e65257c373cb464c294900c21024cf34774923ce01a24faa65508d7b09f29aa50a64e11f204c8f3b2ad7a307ffd53ae"
}
```

And funded it and created a spend transaction.

```
[root@test bin]# bitcoin-cli -testnet listunspent 0 9999 '["tb1qxs6nsj4guvuxftz6pf8gydg6ga4d8flw342y2603vn52vyjm0u3qgxchhk"]'
[
  {
    "txid": "d064d63f54175f6bf4b745cb4019ab92d075a59d18001e00be7eaaa760add2c7",
    "vout": 1,
    "address": "tb1qxs6nsj4guvuxftz6pf8gydg6ga4d8flw342y2603vn52vyjm0u3qgxchhk",
    "label": "",
    "scriptPubKey": "00203435384aa8e33864ac5a0a4e82351a476ad3a7ee8d544569f164e8a6125b7f22",
    "amount": 0.00004000,
    "confirmations": 0,
    "spendable": false,
    "solvable": false,
    "safe": false
  }
]

[root@test bin]# bitcoin-cli -testnet createrawtransaction '[{"txid":"d064d63f54175f6bf4b745cb4019ab92d075a59d18001e00be7eaaa760add2c7","vout":1,"scriptPubKey":"00203435384aa8e33864ac5a0a4e82351a476ad3a7ee8d544569f164e8a6125b7f22","redeemScript":"522102b1c24ff14bc3e9cab5ff65eda5365fc215449b8fbacb7615a6c8fe0c64ea2bba21039e28363fe72c1d84b04a15e491f3e85ee853be9f6e65257c373cb464c294900c21024cf34774923ce01a24faa65508d7b09f29aa50a64e11f204c8f3b2ad7a307ffd53ae"}]' '{"tb1qnkvqy9p399dcjuqtmw8d6c49u53nf66g5z238w":0.000036}'
0200000001c7d2ad60a7aa7ebe001e00189da575d092ab1940cb45b7f46b5f17543fd664d00100000000ffffffff01100e0000000000001600149d98021431295b89700bdb8edd62a5e52334eb4800000000

[root@test bin]# bitcoin-cli -testnet signrawtransactionwithkey 0200000001c7d2ad60a7aa7ebe001e00189da575d092ab1940cb45b7f46b5f17543fd664d00100000000ffffffff01100e0000000000001600149d98021431295b89700bdb8edd62a5e52334eb4800000000 '["cVoNiYk51W5E6xos2sMvP7XsR8QhDsw8JR6dof9cHw7S1UsechZd"]' '[{"txid":"d064d63f54175f6bf4b745cb4019ab92d075a59d18001e00be7eaaa760add2c7","vout":1,"scriptPubKey":"00203435384aa8e33864ac5a0a4e82351a476ad3a7ee8d544569f164e8a6125b7f22","redeemScript":"522102b1c24ff14bc3e9cab5ff65eda5365fc215449b8fbacb7615a6c8fe0c64ea2bba21039e28363fe72c1d84b04a15e491f3e85ee853be9f6e65257c373cb464c294900c21024cf34774923ce01a24faa65508d7b09f29aa50a64e11f204c8f3b2ad7a307ffd53ae"}]'
error code: -3
error message:
Missing amount for CTxOut(nValue=21000000.00000000, scriptPubKey=00203435384aa8e33864ac5a0a4e82)
```

I encountered an error, but solved it by adding address to tx data.

```
[root@test bin]# bitcoin-cli -testnet createrawtransaction '[{"txid":"d064d63f54175f6bf4b745cb4019ab92d075a59d18001e00be7eaaa760add2c7","vout":1,"scriptPubKey":"00203435384aa8e33864ac5a0a4e82351a476ad3a7ee8d544569f164e8a6125b7f22","redeemScript":"522102b1c24ff14bc3e9cab5ff65eda5365fc215449b8fbacb7615a6c8fe0c64ea2bba21039e28363fe72c1d84b04a15e491f3e85ee853be9f6e65257c373cb464c294900c21024cf34774923ce01a24faa65508d7b09f29aa50a64e11f204c8f3b2ad7a307ffd53ae", "amount":0.00004}]' '{"tb1qnkvqy9p399dcjuqtmw8d6c49u53nf66g5z238w":0.000036}'
0200000001c7d2ad60a7aa7ebe001e00189da575d092ab1940cb45b7f46b5f17543fd664d00100000000ffffffff01100e0000000000001600149d98021431295b89700bdb8edd62a5e52334eb4800000000

[root@test bin]# bitcoin-cli -testnet signrawtransactionwithkey 0200000001c7d2ad60a7aa7ebe001e00189da575d092ab1940cb45b7f46b5f17543fd664d00100000000ffffffff01100e0000000000001600149d98021431295b89700bdb8edd62a5e52334eb4800000000 '["cVoNiYk51W5E6xos2sMvP7XsR8QhDsw8JR6dof9cHw7S1UsechZd"]' '[{"txid":"d064d63f54175f6bf4b745cb4019ab92d075a59d18001e00be7eaaa760add2c7","vout":1,"scriptPubKey":"00203435384aa8e33864ac5a0a4e82351a476ad3a7ee8d544569f164e8a6125b7f22","redeemScript":"522102b1c24ff14bc3e9cab5ff65eda5365fc215449b8fbacb7615a6c8fe0c64ea2bba21039e28363fe72c1d84b04a15e491f3e85ee853be9f6e65257c373cb464c294900c21024cf34774923ce01a24faa65508d7b09f29aa50a64e11f204c8f3b2ad7a307ffd53ae", "amount":0.00004}]'
{
  "hex": "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",
  "complete": false,
  "errors": [
    {
      "txid": "d064d63f54175f6bf4b745cb4019ab92d075a59d18001e00be7eaaa760add2c7",
      "vout": 1,
      "witness": [
        "",
        "30440220195bd6db9ad006c953e1d093faab2044a7238a04061575d43421487b97767b7202206ae6acabeb123c3e621b4199d894a3cde00cede6abfe95cd2e19e68baede5e0301",
        "",
        "522102b1c24ff14bc3e9cab5ff65eda5365fc215449b8fbacb7615a6c8fe0c64ea2bba21039e28363fe72c1d84b04a15e491f3e85ee853be9f6e65257c373cb464c294900c21024cf34774923ce01a24faa65508d7b09f29aa50a64e11f204c8f3b2ad7a307ffd53ae"
      ],
      "scriptSig": "",
      "sequence": 4294967295,
      "error": "CHECK(MULTI)SIG failing with non-zero signature (possibly need more signatures)"
    }
  ]
}
```

Finally, I got the spend transaction. I signed it with another wallet and tried broadcasting it.

```
[root@develop bin]# bitcoin-cli -testnet sendrawtransaction 02000000000101c7d2ad60a7aa7ebe001e00189da575d092ab1940cb45b7f46b5f17543fd664d0010000006a47304402200569cb5c803b6e37debb7417ddd7882d31267f6be761302e4484bc3e6b4eb62f02206bd37ca84156e9f32862038e520781a561f97c70441eeb3734c224cc31cace9b0121039e28363fe72c1d84b04a15e491f3e85ee853be9f6e65257c373cb464c294900cffffffff01100e0000000000001600149d98021431295b89700bdb8edd62a5e52334eb4804004730440220195bd6db9ad006c953e1d093faab2044a7238a04061575d43421487b97767b7202206ae6acabeb123c3e621b4199d894a3cde00cede6abfe95cd2e19e68baede5e03010069522102b1c24ff14bc3e9cab5ff65eda5365fc215449b8fbacb7615a6c8fe0c64ea2bba21039e28363fe72c1d84b04a15e491f3e85ee853be9f6e65257c373cb464c294900c21024cf34774923ce01a24faa65508d7b09f29aa50a64e11f204c8f3b2ad7a307ffd53ae00000000
error code: -26
error message:
non-mandatory-script-verify-flag (Witness requires empty scriptSig) (code 64)
```

But got this error.

```
[root@develop bin]# bitcoin-cli -testnet decoderawtransaction 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
{
  "txid": "0aa837cedcc84ff726b8f9ec4dafedee0d1ce46f8d64dfd222065900a5e63d55",
  "hash": "ebdf0df0e81eda872cec80f784b1e5003028c6c28385c5c817f23d2c8041a85d",
  "version": 2,
  "size": 371,
  "vsize": 234,
  "weight": 935,
  "locktime": 0,
  "vin": [
    {
      "txid": "d064d63f54175f6bf4b745cb4019ab92d075a59d18001e00be7eaaa760add2c7",
      "vout": 1,
      "scriptSig": {
        "asm": "304402200569cb5c803b6e37debb7417ddd7882d31267f6be761302e4484bc3e6b4eb62f02206bd37ca84156e9f32862038e520781a561f97c70441eeb3734c224cc31cace9b[ALL] 039e28363fe72c1d84b04a15e491f3e85ee853be9f6e65257c373cb464c294900c",
        "hex": "47304402200569cb5c803b6e37debb7417ddd7882d31267f6be761302e4484bc3e6b4eb62f02206bd37ca84156e9f32862038e520781a561f97c70441eeb3734c224cc31cace9b0121039e28363fe72c1d84b04a15e491f3e85ee853be9f6e65257c373cb464c294900c"
      },
      "txinwitness": [
        "",
        "30440220195bd6db9ad006c953e1d093faab2044a7238a04061575d43421487b97767b7202206ae6acabeb123c3e621b4199d894a3cde00cede6abfe95cd2e19e68baede5e0301",
        "",
        "522102b1c24ff14bc3e9cab5ff65eda5365fc215449b8fbacb7615a6c8fe0c64ea2bba21039e28363fe72c1d84b04a15e491f3e85ee853be9f6e65257c373cb464c294900c21024cf34774923ce01a24faa65508d7b09f29aa50a64e11f204c8f3b2ad7a307ffd53ae"
      ],
      "sequence": 4294967295
    }
  ],
  "vout": [
    {
      "value": 0.00003600,
      "n": 0,
      "scriptPubKey": {
        "asm": "0 9d98021431295b89700bdb8edd62a5e52334eb48",
        "hex": "00149d98021431295b89700bdb8edd62a5e52334eb48",
        "reqSigs": 1,
        "type": "witness_v0_keyhash",
        "addresses": [
          "tb1qnkvqy9p399dcjuqtmw8d6c49u53nf66g5z238w"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

What's wrong with my method? What do I have to do if I want a **bech32** multisig address?

Answer (score 1):

> Finally, I got the spend transaction. I signed it with another wallet and tried broadcasting it.

This wallet filled the scriptSig instead of the witness.

Here is a step-by-step P2WSH multisig I made on regtest:

Generate two addresses:

```
$ bcreg1 getnewaddress
2MsPUyivVzHR236LybpdVN7JUaTETQfGwYM
$ bcreg1 getnewaddress
2MyTveMpMuXLVsgEuwACM6ZuRsH5GS2TuFk
```

For each address, get the public key:

```
$ bcreg1 getaddressinfo 2MsPUyivVzHR236LybpdVN7JUaTETQfGwYM |grep pub
$ bcreg1 getaddressinfo 2MyTveMpMuXLVsgEuwACM6ZuRsH5GS2TuFk |grep pub
```

And create a multisig script with those:

```
$ bcreg1 createmultisig 2 "[\"0327c98b3913b9f4e17f2b783ecb632a065067afda3f7619c6f3cf8b7450f24412\",\"026d1ab02d0c1bad3319d1d77c45187e30ef1145094d6e8c18f4a0f0b897f6a11d\"]"
```

Fund an output paying to that script:

```
$ bcreg1 sendtoaddress bcrt1q49mxte3mzw8e2j8k7gryvg4exezfjsmeuw80xjp3704lhnmxfz6s9zl7gc 1
```

Create a transaction spending the above one (I generated another address for this transaction's output):

```
$ bcreg1 createrawtransaction "[{\"txid\":\"e46828bf1e6eb0f465bb2e89ae76d7cc7acb71bbddff64c7911fb4717252a549\", \"vout\":0}]" ["{\"bcrt1qnc6kuzpmumw5qk07yf89surujdwrunyqxjyyed\":1}]"
```

Get the private keys of the two pubkeys from which you created the multisig:

```
$ bcreg1 dumpprivkey 2MsPUyivVzHR236LybpdVN7JUaTETQfGwYM
$ bcreg1 dumpprivkey 2MyTveMpMuXLVsgEuwACM6ZuRsH5GS2TuFk
```

Then sign the transaction with **both** private keys (You missed that step by specifying only one key):

```
$ bcreg1 signrawtransactionwithkey 020000000149a5527271b41f91c764ffddbb71cb7accd776ae892ebb65f4b06e1ebf2868e40000000000ffffffff0100e1f505000000001600149e356e083be6dd4059fe224e58707c935c3e4c8000000000 "[\"cRQN9dxDNsPbZygyto9sjvnMFDu8hb7ghSFJwu8dJk3f1ZNVoQv3\", \"cSJD9VfWgfpgPE9K6dAZLXsUHG4Y5e7cyhBypPsjnzBNP5iuUjXv\"]" "[{\"txid\":\"e46828bf1e6eb0f465bb2e89ae76d7cc7acb71bbddff64c7911fb4717252a549\", \"vout\":0, \"scriptPubKey\":\"0020a97665e63b138f9548f6f2064622b93644994379e38ef34831f3ebfbcf6648b5\", \"witnessScript\":\"52210327c98b3913b9f4e17f2b783ecb632a065067afda3f7619c6f3cf8b7450f2441221026d1ab02d0c1bad3319d1d77c45187e30ef1145094d6e8c18f4a0f0b897f6a11d52ae\", \"amount\":1}]"
```